# Error during bundle: Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, types, monorepo

I got the following error while trying to build a lib using AngularJS with Typescript in my Nx monorepo.`
`Error during bundle: Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)`
This is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "typeRoots": ["../../node_modules/@types", "./types"]
  },
  "files": [],
  "include": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./.storybook/tsconfig.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note I declare "../../node_modules/@types" because I am inside a monorepo lib folder. I've declared a custom types to allow html declarations in my ts files. I am using "typescript": "4.2.4"

This is the result is giving me using verbose flag.

````
verbose stack Error: app@0.0.1 nx: `nx "build" "components-angularjs"`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)```
````